# PHP strftime returns false

Tags: php, strftime

I'm usign `strftime("%e %B %Y", 1344557429)`

It returns `false` but it should return a date in this format `"10 August 2012"` according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: "As the output is dependent upon the underlying C library, some conversion specifiers are not supported. On Windows, supplying unknown conversion specifiers will result in 5 E_WARNING messages and return **FALSE**." Also from the docs you are directing to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read manual first:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Find huge red box:

> Windows only: **The %e modifier is not supported in the Windows
>   implementation of this function.** To achieve this value, the %#d
>   modifier can be used instead. The example below illustrates how to
>   write a cross platform compatible function.

While making new code is common practice to set error_reporting to E_ALL so you can easily find errors.

Answer (score 2):

For a single date use:

```
$format = '%B '.((strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') ? '%#d' : '%e').', %Y';
$date = strftime($format, $unix_timestamp);
```

The PHP docs solution is good as a function:

```
function fixed_strftime($format, $unix_timestamp) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
        $format = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#', '\1%#d', $format);
    }
    return strftime($format, $unix_timestamp);
}
```

Source: http://codeitdown.com/php-strftime-e-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the solution, thanks to @Peter Szymkowski. I'm blind

```
<?php

// Jan 1: results in: '%e%1%' (%%, e, %%, %e, %%)
$format = '%%e%%%e%%';

// Check for Windows to find and replace the %e 
// modifier correctly
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
    $format = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#', '\1%#d', $format);
}

echo strftime($format);
?>
```